# Need help positioning background images with CSS

Tags: css, background-image

This is my first attempt at a non-table layout and I'm really struggling. I've literally been spending hours with trial-and-error and researching/reading posts and articles. So before anyone says "asked and answered" and recommends closing this question, please hear me out and provide some suggestions. Thank you very much.

I have two images, one for the header that goes across the top of the page, and one for the nav menu that should go immediately below the header image on the left. A title will display on top of the header image (no problem there) and a simple unordered list of links will display on top of the nav image. The nav image should, obviously, seamlessly display as if "connected" to the top image. I will be using a php include to put those on all of the site's pages, and after those two images & the menu get positioned properly, I will be putting the individual page's contents below the header and to the right of the nav menu.

My struggle at this point is trying to figure out a) why the nav image won't display at all, and b) why the menu is displaying in the middle of the page.

If I just use an img tag for the nav image, it shows on the page, so I know it's not that the browser can't "find" it...

Is the nav image not displaying because it's in a div? What am I missing here?

I also need this to be as cross-browser-compatible as possible (IE7+, FF3.6+, Safari, Chrome at a minimum).

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Some Website</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 50%; padding; 0; width: 1000px; font-size: .8em; background-image: url(images/header.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center top;">

    <div id="navMenu" style="background-image: url(images/navBackground.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: 0px 200px;">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Business Directory</li>
            <li>City Government</li>
            <li>Community Calendar</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>The Story of the Thing</li>
            <li>The History of Somewhere</li>
            <li>The Park</li>
            <li>Churches and Schools</li>
            <li>Recreation</li>
            <li>Fire Department</li>
            <li>Map</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

For reference, header.png is 1000x200px and navBackground.png is 200x500px

Comment: I assume Enrico added the code - thanks. Sorry about that - I was relying on people visiting the link and viewing the source code themselves, but I see that it would be more helpful to also post the relevant code here as asked!

Comment: **UPDATE (after Joel's and Matthew's answers):** Currently, I now have the images positioned as needed (I see I still have to make some adjustments to them to make them visibly mesh better, though - not a big deal) - with one exception, though: the nav image and menu both scroll with the page - that needs to be stationary as well. I tried setting an -attachment value on the nav's div with no results.

I also need to get the content (in a <div id="content"> tag) to be positioned below and to the right of the header and nav sections, respectively.

Comment: I've been going through this tutorial: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ and I am still not able to get the nav menu and image to stop scrolling (and move the content div to where I need it to be).

Answer (score 2):

The reason the background image is not showing up is because you are using the "background-attachement: fixed". By removing that, your backgrounds position will be relative to the container of which it is attached.

The other issue is the navs position. The style "margin: 50%" is going to take the percentage of the pages width and apply it to all 4 sides of the container. By setting a static width in pixels, or using shorthand to set the margins correctly, you should get a more desirable outcome. Here is an example of the shorthand I would use "margin: 200px auto". That will line it up in a better position. To find more about shorthand check out this page: http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/

Also, I would recommend externalizing your stylesheet to clean up your markup. Basically, you link to the stylesheet in the head of your document and target the elements with class names and IDs. Check out this post: http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php

Comment: I agree on separating the styling - I'm just using inline right now until I get things straightened out and working properly (easier to make quick changes instead of switching back and forth between files). I'll take a look at your (and Joel's) answers here in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you can remove this css from #navMenu

```
#navMenu { background-attachment: fixed; }
```

you may also want ot double check the background-position of the image.

if you get rid of that, the background image should show up.

As far as the second issue goes, it is centered on the page due to the body of your page having a margin of 50%. That will causes everything to be centered like that.